# Why is MySQL "using_where" with this query?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I have this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM items i
WHERE i.user_id = 1 AND i.source_id = 34
ORDER BY i.time DESC LIMIT 0, 30;
```

And this composite index:

```
idx_user_src_time (user_id, source_id, time)
```

Explain shows that MySQL is indeed using the index:

```
# id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, filtered, Extra
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'ui', 'ref', 'PRIMARY,idx_source_id,idx_user_src_time', 'idx_user_src_time', '8', 'const,const', '329', '100.00', 'Using where'
```

But in the extra column says he needs to perform some *where*.

Could somebody explain me why MySQL needs to perform additional stuff with this query and doesn't have enough with the index???

**EDIT**

If I remove the order by clause, the EXPLAIN remains the same (uses the same index) but the using_where dissapears.

**EDIT**

The table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `source_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `time` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`item_id`)
  KEY `idx_iid_user_src_time` (`item_id`,`user_id`,`source_id`,`time`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `idx_user_time` (`user_id`,`time_order`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Because MySQL believes that is the best way to execute the query.  How large is the table?

Comment: If you are selecting `*`, there are table columns that need to be pulled that may not be in the index.

Comment: How many records on the items table? How many of those records has a user_id of 1 and a source_id of 34?

Comment: Table have 2.284.841 records. With user_id=1 => 3796, with source_id=34 => 365. Do you think it has something to do with this?

Comment: No, just if there WHERE clause narrows the number of records down by a small amount (ie, a large number of records match the WHERE  clause) the index will likely be ignored. Not the case here. Your EXPLAIN suggests that the index is used (assuming you have just abbreviated idx_user_src_time to idx_u_s_t)

Comment: Yes, just an abbreviation, edited. I am concened that this can slow_down the query in some way.

Answer (score 2):

From [Mysql doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html):

> A WHERE clause is used to restrict which rows to match against the next table or send to the client. Unless you specifically intend to fetch or examine all rows from the table, you may have something wrong in your query if the Extra value is not Using where and the table join type is ALL or index. **Even if you are using an index for all parts of a WHERE clause, you may see Using where if the column can be NULL**.

Comment: I read about it but explain doesn't say anything about he is using_index

Comment: @AitorF: In the output of explain, in the `key` field, it shows the index actually chosen for the query.

Comment: You edited it. But none of the 3 columns involved can be NULL.

Comment: In your table, `source_id`, `user_id`, `time` any of these fields cant have NULL values??

Comment: None of them can be NULL

Comment: @AitorF, cannot be NULL as in not supposed to be NULL for your application's needs, or cannot be NULL as in declared `NOT NULL` in your table definition? Can you please run `SHOW CREATE TABLE items` and edit your question with the output?

Comment: The fields are explicitly flagged as NOT NULL. Se the CREATE above.